# I want to come back to original (source) spreasheet after running a macro (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 24 sheets working as a calendar (Month 01, Month 03, ..., Month 24). I have created a button on each to run a macro in hidden sheet "Calendar" which populates data on each MonthXX sheet. The problem is that I could not find a way to replace the last code below in order to aways come back to the sheet where I pressed the button to run the macro. In the current I need to create one code per sheet and assign the button of that sheet to each code.

Please help me :)

```
function EMBARALHAR00() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Calendar'), true);
  
  spreadsheet.getRange('Z4:AA1655').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('AE4:AF1655'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  
  spreadsheet.getRange('AB4:AC1655').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('AG4:AH1655'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Month01'), true);
  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function EMBARALHAR00() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Calendar');
  sh.getRange('Z4:AA1655').copyTo(sh.getRange('AE4:AF1655'));
  sh.getRange('AB4:AC1655').copyTo(sh.getRange('AG4:AH1655'));
}
```

It doesn't matter what sheet you call this from it will stay on the same sheet. Even though you are using all caps in this name which is typically done for cell functions, this is not a cell function.